# AngularJS replace the entire element

Tags: angularjs

Say I have the following:

```
<div myDiv>
   <!-- Some more tags -->
   <div ng-click="run()">Run</div>
</div>
```

I want to replace the entire `<div myDiv>` with a new `<div myDiv>` when `run()` executes. How can I accomplish this with Angular?

Just to be clear: When `run()` is executed, I want the ENTIRE `<div myDiv>` to be fully removed and replaced with a new `<div myDiv>` that I would get through an AJAX call. This is not something like having an initial set of content, and then loading more content.

Comment: This is a very bad way of using Angular. You should be getting JSON/XML from a AJAX call then parsing that into a template, and really should never do direct DOM manipulation except in a directive.

Comment: Can you write more tips for your necessity? I believe has more techniques to execute your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use element directive and then set `replace` property to true:

```
app.directive('myDiv', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>' + 
                      '<div ng-click="run()">Run</div>' +
                  '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.run = function(){
                // do smth here
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Html before rendering:

```
<my-div></my-div>
```

Html after rendering:

```
<div>
   <div ng-click="run()">Run</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I only want to replace the element once run() executes. Right now, this will just execute when the page is loaded and nothing happens when ng-click is invoked.

Comment: @user834045 you are doing something wrong. for example if you want to show other content when clicking on button, you can do it like this: `scope.show = "first"; scope.run = function(){ scope.show = "second"; }`, in template: `<div ng-if="show === 'first'"> initial content </div><div ng-if="show === 'second'"> content after clicking </div>`

Comment: What I want is to basically replace the whole DOM with a new set of DOM. This DOM already contains information, but when run() executes, then I want the entire DOM to be removed, and a new DOM is placed.